# push_back an object into vector

Tags: c++, vector

I have a vector of objects (`vector<Vertex> setOfVertices`) and I want to create a specified number of new objects of in this vector. Is this a proper way to do so?

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    setOfVertices.push_back(Vertex());
```

or is it better to do it like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{  
   Vertex * V = new Vertex();      
   setOfVertices.push_back(*V);
}
```

Do I need to write some kind of destructor in the latter case?

Or would it be better to give up on std:vector and use arrays instead?

Comment: `Vertex V = new Vertex(); ` does that compile for you? It requires a special constructor for `Vertex`.

Comment: I'm really sorry, I forgot about asterisks, editing immediatelly

Comment: Now you have a memory leak.

Comment: 1. Use vector instead of arrays if possible 2. Use smart pointers to avoid memory leaks 3. Avoid bare news and deletes in your code

Comment: Thank you for your answers! I would like to ask, why is this question downvoted so much, I don't see, what is so wrong about it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `second` example has a memory leak.

If what you want is just a "fill" function then `setOfVertices.insert(setOfVertices.end(), 10, Vertex());` is good enough.

However, if what you want instead is insert different `Vertex` objects then

```
// Make sure only a single memory allocation takes place.
setOfVertices.reserve(setOfVertices.size() + 10);

for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    setOfVertices.push_back(Vertex(i));
```

Comment: Thank you for a complete answer!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the "fill" overload of [`std::vector::insert`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/insert/):

```
setOfVertices.insert(setOfVertices.end(), 10, Vertex());
```

There's no need to allocate memory yourself, `std::vector` will do that for you.  All you need to do is pass a "reference" `Vector` for the new elements to copy from.

Comment: Thank you, that is a great solution!